# F# Compiler Service: get a list of names visible in the scope

Tags: f#, f#-compiler-services

How can I get get a list of names visible in the scope with FSC?
I tried this:

```
#r "../../packages/FSharp.Compiler.Service.16.0.2/lib/net45/FSharp.Compiler.Service.dll"
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.SourceCodeServices

do 
    let file = "TestFileName.fsx"
    let checker = SourceCodeServices.FSharpChecker.Create()

    let code = 
        """
let testStr = "x"
t
"""
    async{  
        let! options, _ = checker.GetProjectOptionsFromScript(file,code)
        let! parseRes,checkAnser = checker.ParseAndCheckFileInProject(file, 0, code, options)                               
        match checkAnser with
        | FSharpCheckFileAnswer.Succeeded checkRes ->
            let! decls =
                checkRes.GetDeclarationListInfo(
                    Some parseRes,  //ParsedFileResultsOpt
                    3 ,              //line
                    1 ,              //colAtEndOfPartialName
                    "t" ,            //lineText
                    [ "t" ] ,        //qualifyingNames
                    "" ,             //partialName
                    ( fun _ -> [] )  //getAllSymbols: (unit -> AssemblySymbol list) 
                    )

            if Seq.isEmpty decls.Items then 
                printfn "*no declarations found*" 
            else
                decls.Items 
                |> Seq.sortBy (fun d -> d.Name) 
                |> Seq.truncate 10 
                |> Seq.iter (fun d -> printfn "decl: %s" d.Name)

        | _ -> failwithf "*Parsing did not finish... "        
        } |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

but it only prints "no declarations found". I would expect not only `testStr` but also all the other names that are available by default.
I did not find an example in the [documentation](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/editor.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

qualifyingNames should be an empty list, it’s for dot separated *prefix*, excluding the last (possibly partial) ident. However, there is no a method in FCS that returns unfiltered list of names for scope, yet it’s really easy to add one.

Answer (score 0):

With the answer of vasily-kirichenko and using the current FCS 17.0.1 I came up with this solution:

```
#r "../../packages/FSharp.Compiler.Service.17.0.1/lib/net45/FSharp.Compiler.Service.dll"
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.SourceCodeServices

do 
    let file = "TestFileName.fsx"
    let checker = SourceCodeServices.FSharpChecker.Create()

    let code = 
        """
let testStr = "x"
testStr.
"""
    async{  
        let! options, _ = checker.GetProjectOptionsFromScript(file,code)
        let! parseRes,checkAnser = checker.ParseAndCheckFileInProject(file, 0, code, options)                               
        match checkAnser with
        | FSharpCheckFileAnswer.Succeeded checkRes ->
            let! decls =
                let partialName = PartialLongName.Empty 6 //use any location before before the dot to get all declarations in scope
                //let partialName = PartialLongName.Empty 7 //use the loacation of the dot (7) to get memebers of string
                checkRes.GetDeclarationListInfo(
                    Some parseRes,  // ParsedFileResultsOpt
                    3 ,             // line                   
                    "testStr." ,    // lineText
                    partialName,    // PartialLongName
                    ( fun _ -> [] ) // getAllSymbols: (unit -> AssemblySymbol list) 
                    )

            if Seq.isEmpty decls.Items then 
                printfn "*no declarations found*" 
            else
                decls.Items 
                |> Seq.sortBy (fun d -> d.Name) 
                |> Seq.truncate 10 
                |> Seq.iter (fun d -> printfn "decl: %s" d.Name)


        | _ -> failwithf "*Parsing did not finish... "        
        } |> Async.RunSynchronously
```